# Schedule a simple php file on Cronjob on Godaddy

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I am trying to run a PHP file every 15mins from 6PM. I have set cronjob like this:

```
*/15 18 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
```

can someone confirm if this script will run at 6 PM and after that every 15mins?

The server is in MST standard time. So I have set 6 PM.  I want the script.php to run from 6:00 AM IST to 7:00 PM IST. So I have set 6 PM MST.

In Godaddy, the process is not happening. Is there a way to check the log if cronjob has run successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: This will only run 4 times per day, 18:00, 18:15, 18:30 and 18:45. Is that what you're after? [Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_18_*_*_*).

Comment: Keep in mind, this will run from 6pm in the server's local timezone. That might not match your own timezone.

Comment: Oh I want to run from 6PM and go on everyday every 15mins

Comment: @Phil: Yes. The server time is MST. 6PM so 6:30AM IST.

Comment: I want it to run everyday 6:00AM IST to 7:00PM IST. Every 15mins.

Comment: Couldn't you have just said that in your question?

Comment: @Phil - Ooops. I am sorry! I thought I had written it.

Comment: Why does it keep changing?! First you said 6am IST, now it's 6.30am IST. Which is it you want?

Comment: @Phil My MST calculation is wrong. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The server is in MST standard time... I want the `script.php` to run from 6:00 AM IST to 7:00 PM IST.

Ok, so...

- 06:00 IST is 17:30 MST (previous day)
- 19:00 IST is 06:30 MST (same day)

This presents two problems

1. It crosses the midnight boundary, and
2. The 30 min part of the offset makes it very difficult to create a repeating 15 minute pattern that starts / stops at the right time.

The easy option is to ask your hosting provider to configure your server's timezone or try and use the `CRON_TZ` environment variable if available (probably not with Godaddy).

```
CRON_TZ=Asia/Kolkata

*/15 6-18 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
```

Otherwise, you're left with something (ugly) like this

```
# 5.30pm and 5.45pm
30,45 17 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php

# Every 15 minutes from midnight till 6am and from 6pm till midnight
*/15 0-5,18-23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php

# 6am and 6.15am
0,15 6 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
```

With this approach, you're probably going to run into issues when your server changes between standard and daylight savings time and to be honest, I don't really have an answer for that.

Comment: what is 0-5? So I have put all the three and it will work.

Comment: Midnight (inclusive) till 6am (exclusive). It basically just says, _"is the hour between 0 and 5 (ie 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5)"_

Comment: */15 0-5,18-23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php - This one is taking 0, 5 every 15mins correctly but it is taking hourly for 18-23

Comment: That's not actually possible. How are you coming to that conclusion?

Comment: I tested it in two different servers.

Comment: @SanjanaNair tested _what_, exactly? I can guarantee that it will execute your PHP script every 15 minutes for both sets of hour ranges. There is literally no way that it would only execute hourly for the second range

Comment: Hmm. I was getting hourly data in my database. So that I figured out that could be the issue.

Comment: So I set it like this:

30,45 17 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php     
*/15 0-6 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php     
*/15 18-23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php

I just checked now - It is taking even the midnight time. 00-15, 00:30, 00.45, 01:00, 01:15 data too.

Comment: And this my sever date: Thu Nov  5 18:12:44 MST 2020

Answer (score 2):

This one runs from 18:00 to the end of the day... at every 15th minute past every hour from 18 through 23 on day-of-month 4 in November.

```
*/15 18-23 4 11 * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
```

and then you make a new one starting with 0:00 tonight... at every 15th minute on every day-of-month from 5 through 31 in November.

```
*/15 * 5-31 11 * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
```

And then you make another one ... at every 15th minute in December.

```
*/15 * * 12 * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
```

and in December you turn it into one forever ... removing the "12" with a "*"

Comment: Will this run every day every 15mins.

Comment: I want it to run everyday 6:00AM to 7:00PM IST. Every 15mins. Since the server is MST I have put 18:00 hours

Comment: So if I need run it every minute till 7PM IST then I have to do it like this: 
*/15 18 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
*/15 19 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
*/15 20 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php

Comment: */15 21 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
*/15 22 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
*/15 23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php
*/15 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/ddruva/public_html/site_data/script.php


Like this.

Comment: you can put them all at once in the crontab. they will run one after the other. they do not conflict.